Oauth2 ; credentials from google look ok, but not accepted when connection to gmail using php-imap2
I am using php-imap2 from https://php-imap2.javanile.org/ to access my gmail account therefore to get an access token that I need, I  use the oauth2-google client.
I have tested my access token, received from the oauth2-google client, with https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=.....
and the cleaned result is below. This looks good to me
    {
      "issued_to": "123.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "audience": "123.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "user_id": "123456",
      "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email     https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid",
      "expires_in": 3564,
      "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
      "verified_email": true,
      "access_type": "offline"
    }

However if I use any of the give generated tokens like below
    $server = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}"; 
    $token='a token from google';  
    $result = imap2_open($server, "myemail@gmail.com", $token, OP_XOAUTH2);   

I always get this in the debug output from php-imap2.
DEBUG: [BE9D] Connecting to ssl://imap.gmail.com:993... 
DEBUG: [BE9D] S: * OK Gimap ready for requests from 2003:c6:2f04:d700:bd76:8fff:409d:fe4e p6mb33658010wmq 
DEBUG: [BE9D] C: A0001 AUTHENTICATE ****** [350] 
DEBUG: [BE9D] S: + eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ== 
DEBUG: [BE9D] C: ****** [-2] 
DEBUG: [BE9D] S: A0001 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure) IMAP connection failed:

What is wrong with my credentials?
Is there any other way to get more details?

FYI: https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol - "The scope for IMAP, POP, and SMTP access is https://mail.google.com/" ...not sure your token scopes look right for that

Consider using google's  ready-made sample code for your task: https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/blob/master/php/oauth2.php / https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/wiki/PhpSampleCode

How can I extend the scope to allow access to gmail ? Thought I just need an access token and that' it. Am I wrong ?

You'd have to check the google oauth docs, I can't remember off the top of my head, but I think you set the scope either in the settings when you request the token, and/or in the app registration

As pointed out in the comments by -ADyson, the scope for accessing email
was not specified. As I am using
vendor\league\oauth2-google\src\Provider\Google.php
I had to add this there
protected function getDefaultScopes(): array
    {
        // "openid" MUST be the first scope in the list.
        return [
            'openid',
            'email',
            'profile',
            'https://mail.google.com/',
            
        ];
    }

Now I get the
DEBUG: [33EA] Connecting to ssl://imap.gmail.com:993... 
DEBUG: [33EA] S: * OK Gimap ready for requests from deleted
DEBUG: [33EA] C: A0001 AUTHENTICATE ****** [354] 
DEBUG: [33EA] S: * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LITERAL- SPECIAL-USE APPENDLIMIT=35651584 
DEBUG: [33EA] S: A0001 OK xxxyyyzzz@gmail.com authenticated (Success) 
DEBUG: [33EA] C: A0002 LIST "" "*" 
DEBUG: [33EA] S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "INBOX" 
DEBUG: [33EA] S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Personal" 
DEBUG: [33EA] S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Receipts" 
DEBUG: [33EA] S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Travel" 
DEBUG: [33EA] S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Work" 
DEBUG: [33EA] S: * LIST (\HasChildren \Noselect) "/" "[Gmail]" 
DEBUG: [33EA] S: * LIST (\All \HasNoChildren) "/" "[Gmail]/All Mail" 
DEBUG: [33EA] S: * LIST (\Drafts \HasNoChildren) "/" "[Gmail]/Drafts" 
DEBUG: [33EA] S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren \Important) "/" "[Gmail]/Important"
DEBUG: [33EA] S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren \Sent) "/" "[Gmail]/Sent Mail" 
DEBUG: [33EA] S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren \Junk) "/" "[Gmail]/Spam" 
DEBUG: [33EA] S: * LIST (\Flagged \HasNoChildren) "/" "[Gmail]/Starred" 
DEBUG: [33EA] S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren \Trash) "/" "[Gmail]/Trash" 
DEBUG: [33EA] S: A0002 OK Success

